# Loader not displayed in HTML

Tags: javascript, ajax, image

I have a AJAX file where I am using a loader image to display it while the contents are being loaded. But it seems that something is wrong as it is not being displayed, though the text is displayed!

My code is :

```
http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(http.readyState == 4) {
        //document.getElementById("showBusStatus"+bus_id).innerHTML = http.responseText;
        document.getElementById("showBusStatus").style.color = '#999;';
        //document.getElementById("showBusStatus").style.input.width = '60px;';
        document.getElementById("showBusStatus").innerHTML = http.responseText;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("showBusStatus").innerHTML = '<img src="ajax-loader.gif"> Loading Content...';
    }
}
```

The image file is in the same directory as the Javascript file

Comment: why don't you use jquery ? It would make your work much more easier and your problem would be easier to solve.

Comment: Try closing the `<img>` tag with `/>` at the end - and check the image path is correct. Are there any javascript errors ?

Comment: are you sure, the image is located in the place, where you have set the `src` of the image...

Comment: I have added `/>` ...but same result. Also the image is in the same directory .

Answer (score 0):

Use a URL that is relative to the webroot.

```
<img src="/css/images/ajax-loader.gif" />
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have works - but I suspect the image src is not specified correctly ... see this example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xZttc/1/) it works fine using your code and a loading image found on the web.

JavaScript :

```
http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (http.readyState == 4) {
        document.getElementById("showBusStatus").style.color = '#999;';
        document.getElementById("showBusStatus").innerHTML = "Load complete";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("showBusStatus").innerHTML = '<img src="http://drupal.org/files/54640843-ajax-style-loading-gif-animation.gif" /> Loading Content...';
    }
};
```